# How to determine if a webshop is scam?

Tags: phishing, credit-card, web, scam

Nowadays people prefer to do their shopping online rather than using the real shop, especially because of the COVID-19 restrictions. But in the same context, attackers (scammers) are trying to gain their own interest from this situation. I'm in the middle of one research where we have found hundreds of scam webshops, but still I'm willing to learn more every day.

So question for anyone who needs or want to shop online these days is: **How to determine, spot scam webshop?** What are the main *indicators* pointing to the fact, that it is **not safe** to shop there?

What can a regular user do or check on a website, to be sure that it's safe to do shopping?

Comment: I don't see this really on topic here since it is not about __information__ security. But at the end the indicators are similar to "offline" live: don't only judge by what somebody claims about themselves or how somebody looks but use independent information like reputation, experiences of past customers etc (not the ones claimed on their own site or on similar untrusted sites). And if some offers sound too good to be true they likely are.

Comment: This might be reasonable to ask on [Money.SE]?